# Подскажите порядок действий и алгоритмы?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ребятки, подскажите нубу) Изучаю Python. Решил попрактиковаться. Хочу написать что то наподобие дорвея, генератора страниц по ключам. Задача такая: Есть файл с ключами в столбик например: Audi, BMW, BMW X5, BMW X6. Есть еще один файл со структурой html документа и текстом, в тексте присутствуют ключи типа «KEY» куда нужно подставлять ключи из первого файла. Собственно эти же ключи должны подставлять и в название документа. Так вот как таким образом реализовать? Чтобы программа брала ключ из файла #1 и брала структуру из файла #2 создавала новый файл #3 с именем ключа, сохраняла туда структуру из документа #2 заменив «KEY» из файла #1 и т.д пока ключи в файле #1 не закончатся. ))) Куда копать?) Чет вообще мыслей нет, и что использовать и какие алгоритмы? Уже такая прога есть у меня в виде exe написанном не знаю на чем. Но хочется попробовать для практики написать самому.

Непонятен алгоритм и что использовать для создания файла копирования из другого файла структуры и вставки ключа из третьего файла.

Comment: А вы не пробовали прежде чем браться за написание программы, хотя бы что-нибудь прочитать про питон? У вас же задача из тривиальных вещей состоит: чтение из файла, поиск и замена подстроки, запись в файл. Если бы вы хотя бы начали изучать питон, вы бы уже в первый же вечер знали бы, как это делается.

Answer (score 2):

разбейте вашу задачу на части, например:

- сначала научитесь получать ключи из первого файла в массив (htmlsoup?)
- считайте второй файл, подумайте, как вы можете найти строки/ключи, которые вы хотите заменить - (допустим регулярные выражения, парсинг руками)
- научитесь сохранять массив в файл, научитесь менять значения в строке и сохранять строку в файл.
- для начала тренируйтесь на маленьких примерах (одна-две строки в каждом файле)
- почитайте про шаблонизаторы, типа jinja/jinja2 (аналог на php - twig)

программу за вас здесь никто писать не будет, тем более по такому размытому описанию

Answer (score 2):

1) читаем файл с шаблоном

```
tepmlate = open('tpl.html').read()
```

2) читаем файл с ключами построчно. Теперь знаем общее кол-во ключей.

```
rows = open('mykey')
for row in rows.readlines():
    print(row)
```

3) открываем документ на запись, в котором название равно ключ из текущей строки.

```
file = open(row + 'html', 'w')
```

4) в шаблон вставляем нужное количество ключей, т.к. ключ один достаточно через замену

```
string = tepmlate.replace('key', row)
```

5) пишем в файл

```
file.write(string)
```

6) закрываем файл

```
file.close()
```

7) и так по кругу.

Задача элементарная, гораздо интереснее когда несколько ключей в одном документе.

[Добавлю пример простейшего доргена](https://specialist-seo.ru/media/examples/simpledoor.zip) 8 строк кода, шаблон взял первый попавшийся.

Comment: это если у него шаблон, впрочем, и это тоже будет автору полезно, плюсую

Comment: Для разминки перед своей работой сделал автору пример кода. По шаблонизатору это да, мне лично быстрее на django сделать то что хочу, потом в статику если очень нужно перевести.

Comment: Результат исполнения примера будет в папке page. Делал из под linux, в виндовс возможно кодировку нужно изменить в файле ключей.

Comment: @Igor Огромное спасибо за инфу!!!! Очень полезно! Буду пробовать. Попробовал открыть файл, запустить, выдает ошибку:`   file = open('page/' + row + 'html', 'w')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'page/п»їРіРµРЅРµСЂР°С‚РѕСЂ РґРѕСЂРІРµРµРІ\nhtml'` Кодировку менял на utf8, все равно. Завтра утром попробую разобраться!

Comment: свой файл с ключами вместо моего просто положите.

Comment: для тренировки возьмите англоязычные ключи, с кодировками лучше разбираться когда понимаешь что делаешь. Или можно поставить виртуальную машину и на ней запускать.